# Session Timeout is not working Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, session-timeout

I have set the following property

```
server.servlet.session.timeout=30s
```

in my application properties but the session time out is not triggerd.
but after setting

```
server.servlet.session.cookie.max-age=30s
```

the  session time out got trigger but  following code for updating logout time is not getting triggerd.

```
 @Component
    public class LogoutListener implements ApplicationListener<SessionDestroyedEvent> {
     
   @Override
        public void onApplicationEvent(SessionDestroyedEvent event)
        {
            List<SecurityContext> lstSecurityContext = event.getSecurityContexts();
            UserDetails ud;
            for (SecurityContext securityContext : lstSecurityContext)
            {
                ud = (UserDetails) securityContext.getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        
                us.findAllUsersByEmail(ud.getUsername()).get(0).setLastLogout(LocalDateTime.now());
                System.out.println("lastloginspec : " + ud.getUsername() + " : 00 : " + LocalDateTime.now());
            }
        }
        
        }
    
    
    @Bean
        public ServletListenerRegistrationBean<HttpSessionEventPublisher> httpSessionEventPublisher() {
            return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean<HttpSessionEventPublisher>(new HttpSessionEventPublisher());
    }
```

Could any one Help me out ?

Comment: what is the package of `LogoutListener`,  package of the class that defines `httpSessionEventPublisher` and package of your `@SpringBootApplication` class?

Comment: Do you have any dependancy starting with spring-session ?

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai both are in same package  com.ust.ldesk.security

Comment: 30seconds doesn't make sense, the Thread killing of sessions runs every 1 minute. So session timeout is always at least 1 minute (could be a bit more). Make sure your `LogoutListener` is actually registered and the `@Bean` method should be in an `@Conffiguration` class .

Comment: @Deinum logout listener is configured in configuration class only and time out is set 120 seconds still it not working

Comment: @AkshayPrabhu, did you try the answer below and if so, is it printing `event caught at  LogoutListener` for any events?

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented the session listener by following way.

1. Create a custom http session listener.

   ```
   @Component
   public class CustomHttpSessionListener implements HttpSessionListener{

   private static final Logger LOG= LoggerFactory.getLogger(Test.class);

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se) {
        LOG.info("New session is created.");
        UserPrincipal principal = (UserPrincipal) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
        LOG.info("Session destroyed.");
        UserPrincipal principal = (UserPrincipal) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();


    }}
   ```
2. Invoke new ServletListenerRegistrationBean and add CustomHttpListener to it and annotate it as @Bean.

   ```
   @Autowired private CustomHttpSessionListener customHttpSessionListener;

   @Bean 
   public ServletListenerRegistrationBean<CustomSessionListner>sessionListenerWithMetrics() {  ServletListenerRegistrationBean<CustomSessionListner>
        listenerRegBean = new ServletListenerRegistrationBean<>();
        listenerRegBean.setListener(customHttpSessionListener);
        return listenerRegBean;
   }
   ```
3. Adding a property to application.properties

   `server.servlet.session.timeout = 15m`

Answer (score 0):

- This is not a full answer, but a step to isolate and troubleshoot. Replace your `LogoutListener` with and see when you start the application if it is printing any events. If it is not printing your issue is not specific `SessionDestroyedEvent` instead generic to your listener.

```
     @Component
     public class LogoutListener 
         implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationEvent> {

     @Override
     public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent event)
     {
        System.out.println("event caught at  LogoutListener: " + event);
      }

    }
```

- And also add this to `application.properties` to see if event is fired as it should log `Publishing event:`

```
    logging.level.org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher=DEBUG
```