# Spring Boot session expires during POST request

Tags: java, spring-boot, session, tomcat, spring-security

I have a Spring Boot/Spring Security application made via Java 16 and Spring Boot v2.7.5 and running on embedded Tomcat server.
The strange thing about it that I've indicated session timeout to 4 hours using application.properties (can be found below), but **when I do POST request after e.g. 3.5 hours of inactivity the session expires** despite this setting and redirects me to login screen. Moreover, I've done several checks to investigate this issue and I've figured out that **if I do a GET request instead then the session remains** and then I can do any request I want without timeout.

**Could you advise what can trigger such behaviour, please?**

My first thoughts were about cookies and/or CSRF token lifetime. However, looks like CSRF token has no expiration time and it remains the same all the time the session exists. The same thing is about JSESSIONID cookie behavior by default. However, I also tried to set server.servlet.session.cookie.max-age property to 4 hours and it didn't work neither.

Please note, that if I set session timeout to quite lower values like default 30 minutes, everything works as intended. Also, I've checked session timeout internaly after server is running using RestController and calling HttpServletRequest.getSession().getMaxInactiveInterval() and the returning value was always equal to server.servlet.session.timeout value, so looks like nothing overrides this property or something.

Thank you for the answers in advance!

Please take a look at my application.properties document below:

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://uri;databaseName=DBName
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=pwd

spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=400000
spring.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout=600000
spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime=1800000

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.show-sql=false

server.servlet.session.timeout=240m

server.error.whitelabel.enabled=true
server.error.include-message=never
server.error.include-binding-errors=never
logging.file.path=./log/

spring.web.resources.cache.cachecontrol.no-store=true
spring.web.resources.cache.cachecontrol.must-revalidate=true

spring.mail.host=smtp.com
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.trust=smtp.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=user@email.com
spring.mail.password=pwd
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true

server.port=443

server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-store=keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=pwd
server.ssl.key-alias=tomcat
```

Comment: interesting. can you try this instead ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/63214800/2165146

Comment: @muhammedozbilici I've implemented those sessions listeners and created 2 sessions. The session's timeout was set to 4 hours. In a 3 hours I sent a POST request in the first session and instatnly received the log message stating that the session was destroyed. Then I sent a GET request in another session and the 2nd session remains alive.